# How to remove unwanted header?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, books

I've made a page of my book for the conclusion, is only one page so I don't want to make a true chapter for it because is only one page so I've used `\chapter*{}`.
The problem is that the next page header has the header of the previous chapter so it seems a part of the previous chapter. I've made a MWE if you notice page 4 has the header of the Chapter 1. How can I fix it? How can I remove this wrong header?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{G M}
\title{How to remove unwanted heading?} 
\begin{document}
\chapter[THIS IS THE FIRST CHAPTER NOT THE CONLCUSION]{Test}
\lipsum[3-10]
\chapter*{Conclusion}
\lipsum[10-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
\markboth{}{}
```

to remove the headers:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{G M}
\title{How to remove unwanted heading?} 
\begin{document}
\chapter[THIS IS THE FIRST CHAPTER NOT THE CONLCUSION]{Test}
\lipsum[3-10]
\chapter*{Conclusion}
\markboth{}{}
\lipsum[10-20]
\end{document}
```

Or `\markboth{Conclusion}{}` to have the text "Conclusion" in the header.

An image of the top of page four using the first option:

[image]

Comment: In my case, `\markboth{}{Conclusion}` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Loading the `emptypage` package solves the problem in a different way and I recommend it anyway, because it removes headers and footers from otherwise empty pages.

Of course, this wouldn't solve the issue if the conclusions chapter is longer than one page.

Another strategy, if you don't have appendices or other numbered material, is to issue

```
\backmatter
\chapter{Conclusions}
```

because after `\backmatter` chapter numbers are suppressed.

However, why should this chapter be unnumbered in the first place?

Comment: Excellent I didn't know about this package! I thought that a chapter with only one page wasn't very beautiful then is only a page where are reported the most interesting things from other chapters.